# Coq Decision Diagram Multivalued Function

Tags: coq

I am trying to accomplish something but am stuck.

To begin with, my work is based on a List Decision Diagram. This represents a multi-valued input binary output function.
[image]

Here, assume we have natural numbers as input values with a maximum value of p.

We define a Shannon Expansion on this function by testing whether a value is satisfying for this function, and computing the cofactor of this.
[image]
So this function requires that the input is 0 for the first variable. It tests using a literal whether 0 is accepted, and if so, sets the first variable to 0. Otherwise, it will continue to the next value, which is 1.

For such functions, we define a DAG structure. This is very similar to BDDs. We keep it simple for now.

```
   Inductive ldd := 
      | Vertex (v : variable) (n : nat) (down_edge: ldd) (right_edge: ldd)
      | Leaf (val: Prop).
   Record ldd_var := Var { var_car : nat }.
```

This represents the following function.
[image]
Thus, in a vertex, we have a variable (v), a label (n) and two direct children.
The important factor, that I leave out for simplicity, is that LDDs must be of equal depth along the right edges to remain canonical. Furthermore, the right child may never be the true terminal vertex, and the down child may never be the false terminal vertex.

Now, I create a context for this LDD. We bind the variables to a nat as follows.

```
  Definition var_bind : Type := ldd_var -> nat.
  Definition eq_bind (vb1 vb2 : var_bind) : Prop := 
      ∀ (v : ldd_var), vb1 v = vb2 v.
```

And we can then restrict the value for this variable as follows.

```
  Definition update (vb : var_bind) (v : ldd_var) (n : nat) : var_bind :=
      λ x : ldd_var, if eq_dec v x then n else vb x.
```

In the end, we represent the original function that an LDD represents as

```
  Definition fun_inclusive := var_bind → bool.
```

To evaluate this function,

```
  Definition eval_fun_inclusive (fi : fun_inclusive) (vb : var_bind) := fi vb.
```

Now, however, I would like to create a construct/type of a function that can be extracted from the LDD. This needs to be done such that we can test whether the LDD correctly represents a function. For example, it must be the case that if we follow a down edge in the LDD, we restrict, i.e. update, a variable with a value. Thus, we need to have a definition that represents this choice, and we can prove a Lemma that choosing this path is equal to restricting the real function to that value. (see Shannon Expansion)

In the end, I would like to then, together with the var_bind, interpret this to the fun_inclusive type.

Can someone help me with my endeavours? I am looking for ideas on how to handle this problem. The real problem I am stuck on, is that we need to represent that there is a maximum value of p for this input, that it is an n-ary function and that we need to be able to prove that the choice for the Shannon Expansion is equal to the choice in the LDD.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for ideas on how to handle this problem.

Very generally: I'd first define an abstract syntax for these functions (i.e. not use Coq functions directly, or you'd have to go meta-coq to reason about specific definitions) up to an evaluator or a solver (etc.); then I would define the LDD encoding of the same kind of functions, correspondingly up to an evaluator or a solver; finally rather proofs of equivalence between the two sides up to any level needed.  Thinking the part using functions as the specification, the part using LDD's as the implementation, equivalence is a proof of correctness of the implementation.

> The real problem I am stuck on, is that we need to represent that there is a maximum value of p for this input [...]

The problem you are asking about is already non-trivial (a lot of code already), so, as long as you have some general path clear, it might be more appropriate (for SO) asking separate and focused coding questions on minimal examples.  (All the more so since your functions are not simply boolean functions, and the definition of "rooted Shannon expansion" that you picture and describe is not totally precise, or I cannot fully parse it.)